Why does my chosen method for finding the cube roots of -1 only work for two of the roots?
The problem:
Find the three cube roots of -1.
The answer:
$-1, \frac{1}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$
What I have tried:
I KNOW there are other posts on this forum with this exact problem, but my issue with it is a little different, which I'll soon explain.
I began by finding out the modulus and argument, and I got the following:
$r=\lvert-1\rvert=1$
$\theta=\pi$
To find out the roots I chose this following formula because it made the most sense to me:
$z=z_k=r^{\frac{1}{k+1}}\cdot e^{i\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{k+1}}$
This formula worked fine for $k=0$ and $k=2$ where I got the following roots:
$z_0=e^{\pi{i}}=\cos{\pi}+i\sin{\pi}=-1+i\cdot 0=-1$
$z_2=e^{i\frac{5\pi}{3}}=\cos{\frac{5\pi}{3}}+i\sin{\frac{5\pi}{3}}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$
My chosen method seems to work fine for two of the roots as they're correct. But when I try to find out the third root, that is when I run into trouble.
$z_1=1^{\frac{1}{1+1}}\cdot e^{i\frac{\pi+2\cdot 1 \cdot \pi}{1+1}}=1^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot e^{i\frac{\pi+2\pi}{2}}=e^{i\frac{\pi+2\pi}{2}}=e^{i\frac{3\pi}{2}}=\cos{\frac{3\pi}{2}}+i\sin\frac{3\pi}{2}=0-1\cdot i=-i$
This root is not a root of $-1$. The missing root is:
$e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}}=\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}}+ i\sin\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$
Should I scrap this method entirely as I do not get all the three roots? Or am I making a mistake in my calculation?

$\theta=\pm\pi,$ or $3\pi.$

Also, you've got a $$\cdot$ where you presumably meant $+$ in your last calculation.

I found a different formula that works fine and gave me the roots. Do I delete this post?

Note, mathematicians normally won't write $\sqrt[3]{-1}$ when they want to include complex roots. Instead. they write $(-1)^{1/3}$ or ask for the roots of $x^3+1=0.$

The formula for (complex) $n^\mathrm{th}$ roots is not the one you used, but $z_k = \sqrt[n]{r},e^{i(\theta+2\pi k)/n}$, $k = 0,1,\ldots,n-1$ instead.

Yup. I found the right formula and was able to solve the problem.

The surprising thing about this formula is that it gives the correct final result in even one case where $k\neq 0$. Dividing exponents by $k+1$ is clearly a bad idea.

That formula is very wrong.  The denominators should be the actual power of the root you are trying to find (in this case $3$) and is constant for all roots.  It should have nothing to do with the index of the root.  The formula you want for the $n$ther root is $z_k = r^{\frac 1{\color{red}n}} e^{i\frac {\theta+2k\pi}{\color{red}n}}$ for $k=0,1,...,n-1$.  I have no idea why your formula divides by $k+1$.

Your formula
$$z_k=r^{\frac{1}{k+1}}\cdot e^{i\frac{\theta+2k\pi}{k+1}}$$
provides a $(k+1)$-th root of $z = re^{i\theta}$. Thus $z_0 = z$ is the "first root" of $z$, $z_1$ is a square root of $z$, $z_2$ is a cubic root of $z$ etc. This is not what you want.
The correct approach to find all $n$-th roots of $z$ is
$$z_k = r^{\frac 1 n}e^{i\frac{\theta + 2k\pi}{n}} , \phantom{x} k = 0, \ldots,n-1 .$$
There are $n$ of them.
For $n=3$ and $z = -1 = e^{i\pi}$ this yields
$$z_0 = e^{i\frac{\pi}{3}} =\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i , z_1 =  e^{i\pi} = -1, z_2 = e^{i\frac{5\pi}{3}} = e^{-i\frac{\pi}{3}} = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt3}{2}i$$

Hint:
$$z^{\frac {1}{n}} = |r_z|^{\frac {1}{n}} \bigg (\cos \frac {k (\theta_z +2 \pi) }{n} + i \sin \frac {k(\theta_z +2 \pi)}{n} \bigg ) $$ where $$k=0, 1, \dots n-1 \\ z=a+bi \\ r_z = \sqrt {a^2+b^2} \\ \theta_z = \arctan \frac {b}{a}$$
